# Is Metro 2033 even released in English anywhere in the English speaking world?

Tags: books, metro-2033

I really want to read Metro 2033, by Dmitry Glukhovsky. I'm having a hard time finding it. To be more precise, I'm having a hard time finding legal copies - there appear to be bootleg English translations on the web.

Amazon's US site (amazon.com) is showing either just the German translation, or they have it marked as not released yet.  If there are bootleg translations, it seems that it must be legally released somewhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There have been a few developments since this question was last asked.  A free digital copy of *Metro 2033* the book is included with all purchases of *Metro Last Light*, the 2013 video game ([Sou](http://www.joystiq.com/2013/04/27/metro-last-light-on-steam-includes-metro-2033-e-book/)[rces](http://goodereader.com/blog/e-book-news/metro-last-light-ebook-to-be-bundled-with-steam-purchase)).

There is also a physical book that was released in early 2013, which you can buy [off Amazon](http://amzn.com/1481845705).

Answer (score 7):

There is a UK translation of Metro 2033 in Amazon's German site.

Here you can take a look directly: [Metro 2033 English](http://www.amazon.de/Metro-2033-Dmitry-Glukhovsky/dp/0575086246/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&s=books-intl-de&qid=1294825312&sr=1-1#reader_0575086246)

Comment: Ah! You linked to amazon US, which has a mix of unreleased and german used book. I found the book on Amazon.uk though. Thanks!

Comment: @matthewmartin perhaps that's a flaw in the SE system of automatically replacing Amazon links?  @iceag would have to say to be sure.

Comment: well, its amazon itself! i placed a link i found on amazon.de and by localisation Matthewmartin was directed to the US-Site.. its like e.g.: type www.google.de and if you are not in Germany you will be directed towards the localised google extension.

Answer (score 2):

A little late to the party but there is a [Metro 2033 audio book](https://www.audible.co.uk/pd/Sci-Fi-Fantasy/Metro-2033-Audiobook/B0082BEE88) read by [Rupert Degas](https://www.audible.co.uk/search/ref=a_pd_Sci-Fi_c2_1_narr?searchNarrator=Rupert%20Degas).